# SimpleDateFormat Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need the DATE_FORMAT for this case: "Thu Feb 17 08:50:02 UTC 2022"
The example code is this:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).parse(s);
```

where DATE_FORMAT is the format that I need to find and "s" is String "Thu Feb 17 08:50:02 UTC 2022"

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The best help we can give you is to recommend you stop using SimpleDateFormat immediately and start using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

`Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse("Thu Feb 17 08:50:02 UTC 2022");`